# When a function is called by another function, what is the technical term for it?

Tags: c, function, terminology

I am trying to solve a riddle given to me where i have to answer questions to decrypt something.

Basically what i had to do was answer these questions:

pointer as a function parameter = call-by? -> reference

0xDeadBeef in decimal? -> 3735928559

what do you call the place in the memory which is created once per call of a function? -> stack

datatype of a non dereferenced pointer? -> void

English term for a function that is given to another function as parameter? -> argument

Those are the solutions i came up with. it says one or more wrong answers, maybe you can help me? the programm doesnt specify which answer is wrong but maybe some of you more experienced coders see where i went wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A stack is not created once per call; a stack *frame* is.

Comment: Thanks this was the keyword that i got wrong. riddle solved :)

Answer (score 2):

the term is `callback`.

You can read more about them for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_science))

The question title is wrong, it's not the same as a function called by another function.
When you say a function called by another function, here's what people understand:

```
void func1()
{
    func2();
}
```

`func2` is called by `func1`

Comment: I tried that one before and it said wrong answers but i might be wrong on other questions too. I'm sorry for my bad english, i translated the questions by best means.

Comment: @ZakRyze as chepner pointed out in his comment, you should replace stack by stack frame

Comment: yes i did that afterwards and got the results :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Giving a function as a parameter to another function requires a pointer to function. A pointer is assigned the start address of a function, thus, by typing the pointer name, program execution jumps to the routine pointed to. By using a single pointer, many different routines could be executed, simply by re-directing the pointer to point to another function. Thus, programs could use this to send information to a printer, console device, tape unit etc, simply by pointing the pointer associated with output to the appropiate output function!
So passing a function as a parameter is called pointer to function.
Stacking a function means calling a function from another function.

Comment: callback was what my prof. expected though. i tried functionpointer earlier too but it said wrong answer. Thanks anyways mate!